# excel vba output all data in active cells in column A to a msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

how do i output all the active cells in for instance column "A" to a msgbox
example file

```
chicken stew
fish    pie
apple   cake
```

msgbox would display

```
chicken
fish
apple
```

this code works

```
MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & vbCrLf &   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
```

but this does not

```
MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Value
```

many thanks

Comment: how would i get this to not display a message box if column A is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would i get this to not display a message box if column A is empty

Try this one

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long, res As String
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Column A is empty"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        res = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A" & lastrow + 1).Value), vbCrLf)
        Do While InStr(1, res, vbCrLf & vbCrLf) ' remove extra vbCrLf (if there're empty rows)
            res = Replace(res, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
        Loop
        MsgBox Left(res, Len(res) - 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: how would i get this to not display a message box if column A is empty

Comment: sorry to be a pain, how would  i get it to display only cells with data in the msgbox ie in my example each rows has data in but the actual file could have blank rows ie

Comment: sorry to be a pain, how would  i get it to display only cells with data in the msgbox ie in my example each row has data in but the actual file could have blank rows but i don't want blank rows in the msgbox                                                                   many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Value
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**:

This version tests if column **A** is empty:

```
Sub dural()
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Column A is empty"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Value
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: how would i get this to not display a message box if column A is empty